# .NET Form Size Scaling Issues

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, scaling, dpi

I've created a small form in Visual Basic .NET. However, when opening the form, I've discovered that when the form's size have been set to a small size, like `67, 67`, the form's window often becomes stretched.

I thought this was a high DPI scaling issue, as I'm using a high DPI screen, so I opened the application release file's `Properties > Compatibility > Change High DPI settings` and selected "Override High DPI scaling issues, scaling performed by `Application`" and I believed that it would solve the problem as usual.

However, I noticed that this did not fix the stretching of the form as I thought it would...

How can I fix this issue so that the actual form's size isn't stretched and reflects the form's size shown in the designer? There are some supplementary screenshots included below...

Designer:

[image: Forms Designer]

Form Properties:

[image: Form Properties]

Result from Debugging and Changing Compatibility Settings (Form Indicated by Blue Arrow)
[image: Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the size in the form loading event. It worked for me.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Size = New Size(67, 61)
End Sub
```